# How to get key values from Html in Flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I have the following html string. how to decode this and get key values

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>order_id=1289&tracking_id=111028965908&bank_ref_no=916831&order_status="
      "Success&failure_message=&payment_mode=Credit Card&card_name=MasterCard&status_code=00&"
      "status_message=Approved¤cy=AED&amount=140.0&billing_name=Gx&billing_address=Yd&billing_city=Ud&"
      "billing_state=&billing_zip=Uf&billing_country=Andorra&billing_tel=4&billing_email=jasir6@gmail.com&"
      "delivery_name=Gx&delivery_address=Yd&delivery_city=Ud&delivery_state=&delivery_zip=Uf&"
      "delivery_country=Andorra&delivery_tel=4&merchant_param1=&merchant_param2=&merchant_param3="
      "&merchant_param4=&merchant_param5=&vault=N&offer_type=null&offer_code=null&discount_value=0.0&"
      "mer_amount=140.0&eci_value=05&card_holder_name=&bank_qsi_no=51000002968&bank_receipt_no=221315916831&"
      "merchant_param6=5123450008
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can go to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) to find the package that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this code if you don't want to use plugin to get key-value data

- Assign a keyValueMap globally if you want to use it anywhere else

  ```
  String html = '<html><head></head><body>order_id=1289&tracking_id=111028965908&bank_ref_no=916831&order_status=Success&failure_message=&payment_mode=Credit Card&card_name=MasterCard&status_code=00&"status_message=Approved¤cy=AED&amount=140.0&billing_name=Gx&billing_address=Yd&billing_city=Ud&billing_state=&billing_zip=Uf&billing_country=Andorra&billing_tel=4&billing_email=jasir6@gmail.com&delivery_name=Gx&delivery_address=Yd&delivery_city=Ud&delivery_state=&delivery_zip=Uf&delivery_country=Andorra&delivery_tel=4&merchant_param1=&merchant_param2=&merchant_param3= &merchant_param4=&merchant_param5=&vault=N&offer_type=null&offer_code=null&discount_value=0.0&mer_amount=140.0&eci_value=05&card_holder_name=&bank_qsi_no=51000002968&bank_receipt_no=221315916831&merchant_param6=5123450008</body></html>';


  onTap: () {
  String temp;
  const start = "<body>";
  const end = "</body>";
  Map<String, dynamic> keyValueMap = {};
  if (html.contains(start)) {
    final startIndex = html.indexOf(start);
    final endIndex = html.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
    temp = html.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
    List splitText = temp.split("&");
    for (var element in splitText) {
      element.runtimeType;
      if (element.contains('=')) {
        keyValueMap[element.split("=")[0] ?? ""] = element.split("=")[1] ?? "";
       }     
      }
    ///You'll get all key value in [keyValueMap]
    }
  },
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use some Html decode plugins. Please go to pub.dev and search flutter_widget_from_html_core, flutter_widget_from_html, html_editor_enhanced,
so many plugins there in pub.dev.